discord.py how to make buttons only usable for person who made the command
alright so i am trying to make a bot that has multiple funny commands, whatever, so i everything was well but then i noticed that other people were clicking the buttons instead of the original person who made the button, i tried to look everywhere how to make it so ONLY the person who executed the command can click the button, but can't figure it out. Please help because people are really abusing that.
buttons src + command src :
class Menu(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = None

    @discord.ui.button(label="Yes, i am sure", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def yesimsure(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):

        if random.randint(1, 10) == 1:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Roulette Result - You Lost!",
                description="You got timed out for 5 minutes.",
                color=discord.Color.red()
            )
            await interaction.message.delete()
            duration = timedelta(minutes=5)
            await interaction.user.timeout(duration, reason="lost roulette looooooserrrrrr")
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
        
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="Roulette Result - You Won!",
                description="Congratulations! You didn't get timed out.",
                color=discord.Color.green()
            )
            await interaction.message.delete()
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

    
    @discord.ui.button(label="No, cancel", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def nuhuh(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Roulette canceled.")



@tree.command(guild = None, name="roulette", description="1 chance in 10 to get timeed out for 5 mins")
async def roulette(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    user_id = interaction.user.id

    if user_id in cooldowns and cooldowns[user_id] > datetime.utcnow():
        await interaction.response.send_message("Nuh uh, you're on cooldown for the roulette!", ephemeral=True)
        return
    
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Roulette Verification",
        description="Are you sure you want to play the roulette?\nYou have 1 chance in 10 to get timed out for 5 minutes.",
        color=discord.Color.blue()
    )

    view = Menu()
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=view)

    cooldowns[user_id] = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=30)

so i tried to search on the web and on this website if there was people with the same issue as me, but couldn't find anything, in last hopes i tried asking chatgpt but as i thought chatgpt is trash for methods and could only give me things that wasn't working at all or was just breaking the entire thing. I also tried to make it ephemeral, which was working, but i would like other people so see the embeds.

The most recommended way to do this is to override the interaction_check method of your view. This method is called before any callback of your view is executed. If it returns False, execution will stop.
class Menu(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, start_interaction: discord.Interaction):
        super().__init__()
        self.start_interaction = start_interaction
        self.value = None

async def interaction_check(interaction: discord.Interaction) -> bool:
    if interaction.user != self.start_interaction.user:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Only the author of the command can perform this action.", ephemeral=True)
        return False
    return True

# append your buttons/selects


@tree.command(guild = None, name="roulette")
async def roulette(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    # ...
    view = Menu(interaction)
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=view)


